# Android Games Save/Load (unity)

Tags: c#, save, load

my saving system is work in unity,but it is not work in android device.I don't know why isn't work and how can I have a saving system in android device.I guess is the path problem.My path is Application.persistentDataPath + " /Score.data"; Is android device would have another specific path or something wrong of my code.

There is my code of saving system

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

public static class savesystem
{
    public static void save(score Score)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + " /Score.data";
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
        Gamedata data = new Gamedata(Score);
        formatter.Serialize(stream, data);
        stream.Close();
    }
    public static Gamedata Load()
    {
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/Score.data";
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
            Gamedata data =formatter.Deserialize(stream) as Gamedata;
            stream.Close();
            return data;

        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("save file not found in" + path);
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: you have a typo in `" /Score.data"`! It should be `"/Score.data"` without the **space** .. voting to close this as typo-based

Comment: is doesn't work. android device can't save